# When to check for mounted before setting state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The docs [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) say that:

> It is an error to call this method after the framework calls dispose.
>   You can determine whether it is legal to call this method by checking
>   whether the mounted property is true.

I have never seen a Flutter example that checks for the `mounted` property, so which cases should we bother to actually check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback. The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() 
>   callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.

quoted from SDK source